# Restart/stop a nodejs server within Sublime Text 2?

Tags: node.js, sublimetext, sublimetext2

I used Sublime Text 2 to download the nodejs package (https://github.com/tanepiper/SublimeText-Nodejs), but I can't seem to find a way that will restart or stop the server besides my having to go into the task manager and killing the process. When using the command provided by the plugin to run the file with node, it doesn't give you any kind of command window, so Ctrl+C won't work.

I've found a couple hackish way of doing things such as a .bat file that looks up the process running on a specific port, then killing it. Then there are a couple linux commands that don't benefit me since I'm on Windows.

I was hoping someone on here would see this and know a solution I could use to easily start and stop the node server for development.

Comment: could you not run node / SublimeText from the command line? I do a lot of stuff with node on unix, and I either run from command line (where control-c works) or use the forever module

Comment: Yeah I could, but I started using ST2 and was trying to make everything inclusive. I mean, there's this giant plugin for nodejs with code completion and everything, but it can't restart the server?

Comment: Node was designed to work from the console. That's just how it is...

Comment: I'm not disputing that. The plugin I linked starts node with the current file open. When it does, it does not give you a console to ctrl-c out of. It also doesn't come prebuilt with a stop/restart command

Comment: Check out `nodemon` or similar npm packages. Could be useful.

Comment: This is closed for an unfathomable reason, at any rate, the answer to your question (and mine) can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20809816/1197730

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think the best solution for you here is to use a module called **Nodemon** which restarts your node server everytime you save a file inside the project.

https://github.com/remy/nodemon

Comment: This is a workaround, but not a solution to the question asked.

Answer (score 18):

If you build your server from sublime using the <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> command it will run the server and then you can kill it by using the default <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>break</kbd> command. Since I am on a laptop that doesn't have a break key I modified the key binding to be something I do have (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>).

Comment: Worked perfectly for me!

Comment: This is the best solution. Can verified it worked.

Comment: +1 though I wish there was a way to stop previous builds that I forgot to cancel before hitting `ctrl-b` again...

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you create a watchdog loop.

1) Start watchdog, with command instructiosn how to restart Node

2) Watchdog monitors your src/ folder and will restart Node when changes detected (you save a file)

There are different watchdog applications and libraries out there, but this is known to work across platforms:

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/watchdog/

At least CoffeeScript compiler can do monitoring internally, so you don't need any kind of third party solution for restarting it automatically. But don't know about barebone Node :(