# EADDRINUSE Node.js Sublime

Tags: node.js, sublimetext3

I have a simple server running on node.js. I get this error when I'm trying to run server second time.

```
var server = new http.Server();
server.listen(8787, '127.0.0.1');
```

How can I stop Node.js server before running it again from **sublime text3** ? For some reason [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13540550/3727662) solution doesn't work for me

Comment: have you tried <kbd>
ctrl
</kbd>
+<kbd>c</kbd>

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/960037/in-sublime-how-to-abort-previous-build-automatically-when-building-again

Comment: Fixed hotkeys binding like in [post][1] I mentioned before and everything works perfect! You also can do "Tools -> Cancel Build" to stop server. Thank a lot!

[1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13540550/3727662